# jquery ui- (slider) custom event binding not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider, custom-events

I have a bit of a problem working out why my custom event does not trigger and work correctly... My custom event should be attached to each column, how can I get the slider to be bound to only one column (cols object below)? With my current code if I click on any col all cols are resized...

I am trying to dynamically resize a table column using a slider that opens inside a little div, if a table is clicked my little dialog is loaded up then to get all current column width and add an event handler my code is:

```
//param: data = current table
function DisplayColumnData(data) {

    var cols = $(data).find("col");

   //attach slider to each col
    $(cols).each(function(i) {

            var that = this;

            var coldata = $("<div class='ui-col-data' />"); 
            var colvalue = $("<span class='ui-col-value' />");
                colvalue.text($(that).attr("width"));

            coldata.text(" >col" + i + ": ").append(colvalue);

            $(".ui-resizer-cols").append(coldata);

            //handle column resizing, bind each col to the slider...
            $(coldata).click(function() {
                $(".ui-col-data").unbind("resizehandler");
                //remove all other binded events then trigger the new event only...
                $(coldata).trigger("resizehandler", that);
            });

    });

}

$(".ui-col-data").live("resizehandler", function(event, data) {
    var $parent = $(this).closest(".ui-resizer-cols");

    //remove classes from all other cols so only the clicked col is resized
    $parent.find(".ui-col-data").removeClass("ui-col-border");
    $parent.find(".ui-col-value").removeClass("ui-resizer-val");

    $(this).addClass("ui-col-border"); //now the active col   

    var valfield = $(this).find("span.ui-col-value");
    valfield.addClass("ui-resizer-val");


    //update whatever...
    $("#ui-resizer").slider('value', valfield.text() );
    $("#ui-resizer").bind("slide", function(e, ui) {
        valfield.text(ui.value);
        $(data).attr("width", ui.value); //update col
    });

});
```

TABLE:

```
<table>
<colgroup>
      <col width="25%">
      <col width="25%">
      <col width="25%">
      <col width="25%">
</colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>...</tr>// 4 td's here as normal
<tr>...</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Slider:

```
<div class="ui-resizer-content">
        <div id="ui-resizer" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <div class="ui-slider-range ui-slider-range-max ui-widget-header" style="width: 100%;"></div><a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="left: 0%;"></a></div>
        <div class="ui-resizer-cols"></div>

           <p> <a href="#" id="lnkResizer" style="float: right;">close</a>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant html as well ?

Comment: all the html is populated on the fly except for the tables and the slider I will update...

Comment: the main problem is related to why the slider event updates more than one column, if I select only one column it will update it fine however if I select column 2 then 2 columns width are updated together...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was not so clear (at least to me) from the documentation but the fix is:

```
 $("#ui-resizer").slider({
                    slide: function(e, ui) {
                        valfield.text(ui.value + "%");
                        $(column).attr("width", ui.value); //update col
                    }
                });
```

Apparantly the code I used (below) is global for all sliders using a single handler, and the fix above is specific to an instance of a slider? (if I have understood correctly)

```
$("#ui-resizer").bind("slide", function(e, ui) { ... }
```